# Get max value of column, min value of column corresponding to rank at once in ms sql

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have this query

```
WITH summary AS 
(
   SELECT  Msisdn, DateRegistered , 
       RANK() OVER  (ORDER BY DateRegistered ASC) AS dRank 
   FROM dbo.SubscriptionsArchive 
   WHERE MSISDN='123456'
)
SELECT s.msisdn, s.DateRegistered AS firstReg 
FROM summary s 
WHERE dRank =(SELECT max(dRank) FROM summary )
```

This displays the firstReg corresponding to the min Rank, I want to get the lastReg corresponding to maxRank at the same time.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: Upvote, good question which allows different solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution by cross joining the first and last line of the CTE, with `TOP 1` syntax:

```
WITH summary AS 
(
   SELECT  Msisdn, DateRegistered , 
       RANK() OVER  (ORDER BY DateRegistered ASC) AS dRank 
   FROM dbo.SubscriptionsArchive 
   WHERE MSISDN='123456'
)
SELECT minrow.*, maxrow.*
FROM 
   (select TOP 1 * from summary order by dRank desc) minrow
   CROSS JOIN
   (select TOP 1 * from summary order by dRank asc) maxrow ;
```

Comment: What about getting msisdn value ?   And how to get all msisdn, and the two value when drank is max and min and whene there is no where MSISDN='123456', ie we do for all value of MSISDN

Comment: This query works for  a MSSISDN, `WITH summary AS (
   SELECT  Msisdn, DateRegistered , RANK() OVER  (ORDER BY DateRegistered ASC) AS dRank FROM dbo.SubscriptionsArchive WHERE MSISDN='123456'
  )
  SELECT MSISDN.*, firstReg.*, prevReg.* FROM
  ( SELECT  TOP 1 s.msisdn AS MSISDN FROM summary s ORDER BY dRank ASC ) AS MSISDN
  CROSS JOIN 
  (SELECT  TOP 1 s.DateRegistered AS FirstReg FROM summary s ORDER BY dRank ASC ) AS firstReg
  CROSS join 
  (select TOP 1 s.DateRegistered AS PrevReg FROM summary s ORDER BY dRank Desc ) AS PrevReg`   How to do same thing for all MSISDN

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH summary AS 
(
   SELECT  Msisdn, DateRegistered , 
       RANK() OVER  (ORDER BY DateRegistered ASC) AS ASCRank, 
       RANK() OVER  (ORDER BY DateRegistered DESC) AS DESCRank 
   FROM dbo.SubscriptionsArchive 
   WHERE MSISDN='123456'
)
SELECT s.msisdn,
(CASE WHEN ASCRAnk=1 THEN s.DateRegistered END)  AS firstReg,
(CASE WHEN DESCRAnk=1 THEN s.DateRegistered END)  AS LASTReg
FROM summary s
```

Comment: This query will list **all** rows from `summary`. But I think the OP wants to get just one single row, containing the maximum and minimum in one line.

Comment: You can add WHERE ASCRank=1 OR DESCRank =1